# How to find root for three equation using bisection method in C language?

Tags: c, bisection

I am able to find a root of one equation :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
double zadanie (double x)
{
return pow(2,3)-2*x-5; //HERE IS EQUATION
}
double err=0.0001; //presnos5 merania
double c;

void bisection (double a,double b)
{
   if (zadanie(a)*zadanie(b)>= 0)
   {
       printf("nespravny interval <a,b>");
       return;
   }
   c = a;
   while ((b-a) >= err)
{
c= (a+b)/2;
   if (zadanie(c)==0.0){
   printf("koren=%lf\n",c);
   break;
   }
   else if (zadanie(c)*zadanie(a) < 0)
   {
   printf("koren = %lf\n",c);
   b = c;
   }
   else{
   printf ("koren = %lf\n",c);
   a = c;
   }//if
   }//while
   }//bisection
int main()
{
    double a,b;
    a=-2;//rosach merania tam sa daju hodnotz z matlabu
    b=10;//rozsah merania tu sa davaju hodnotz z matlabu
    printf("zadanie je x^3-2x^2+3\n");
    printf("a = %lf\n",a);
    printf("b = %lf\n",b);
    bisection(a,b);
    printf("\nkoren urceny bisekciou: %lf, \nerror: %lf\n",c,err);
    return 0;
}//main
```

but I trying to find root for three equation like (for example. Kirchoff law - current equation)

Find all I(current)

```
I1+I2=I3+I4
I2=I5-I3
I3=I2+I4
```

Its possible do this? If get I2 first, next this value i can insert into next equation and so on.

Sorry for english, hope understand what I mean :)

Thank you.

Comment: Bisection is not the best approach for retrieving the 3 roots (note that two of them might be complex anyway). But if you're wedded to the technique then you can always factorise the polynomial with the root that you have, and re-run the bisection to yield the next root, and so on.

Comment: I will try do that, but do you have better idea how to solve this three equation. Left side need to be equal to right side. Thank you :)

Comment: Google "Cardano's Method".